# Pulling log file directory name into the Pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a bit of a strange one. I have loads of logs that I need to trawl. I have done that successfully in Spark & I am happy with it.

However, I need to add one more field to the dataframe, which is the data center.

The only place that the datacenter name can be derived is from the directory path.

For example:

```
/feedname/date/datacenter/another/logfile.txt
```

What would be the way to extract the log file path and inject it into the dataframe? From there, I can do some string splits & extract the bit I need.

My current code:

```
mpe_data = my_spark.read\
    .option("header","false")\
    .option("delimiter", "\t")\
    .withColumn("Datacenter", input_file_name())\
    .csv('hdfs://nameservice/data/feed/mpe/dt=20191013/*/*/*', final_structure)
mpe_data.printSchema()
mpe_data.createOrReplaceTempView("mpe")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the file path using the _input_file_name_ in Spark 2.0+

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name 
df.withColumn("Datacenter", input_file_name())
```

Adding your piece of code as example, once you have read your file use the withcolumn to get the file_name.

```
mpe_data = my_spark.read\
    .option("header","false")\
    .option("delimiter", "\t")\
    .csv('hdfs://nameservice/data/feed/mpe/dt=20191013/*/*/*', final_structure)

mpe_data.withColumn("Datacenter", input_file_name())

mpe_data.printSchema()
```